# Largest collaborative project in history

Tags: linux

Is Linux the largest collaborative project in history?

Now, "large" can be defined in various ways. Let's take it to mean the number of total person-hours spent writing code, debugging, maintaining and all other tasks in relation to building a working piece of software. This excludes things like marketing or support for instance.

By history, I mean the recorded history, roughly 5000 BC onwards.

If you think there are more sensible definitions, I will happily update the question.

Comment: I think the pyramids and any number of other things (old cathedrals, the atom bomb, most large ships) will far exceed linux in terms of total person hours, so it will come down to how you delimit "collaborative".  Even just WRT to software, I am sure there are projects that have consumed much, much more time.

Comment: It depends how you define "Linux", ranging from "just the kernel" to "every piece of software that every distro maintainer has ever shipped."

Comment: I would consider mathematics to be the largest collaborative project in human history.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history, not *nix.